# Html5 says that values are undefined

Tags: javascript, sql, database, sqlite, client-side

This is in a chrome extension and lets say I have this code:

```
var DB = openDatabase('CMPDB', '1.0', 'Database for CMP', 4 * 1024 * 1024); 
LoadFromDB();   

function LoadFromDB() {

    DB.transaction( function(tx)
    {           
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table(X, Y, Z UNIQUE)');

        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM table', [], function (tx, results) {
            var len = results.rows.length;
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {                 
                alert(results.rows.item(i).X.text);
                alert(results.rows.item(i).Y.text);
                alert(results.rows.item(i).Z.text);                         

            }
        });
    });
}
```

Why do all of the alerts come back as undefined presuming that the table had been created prior and that the Dev tools on chrome say that the values are in the table?

Comment: Try doing console.log(result); to inspect the object in the webkit developer console

Comment: First, it's not HTML 5 that says that values are `undefined`, but Chrome's JavaScript interpreter V8 (yes, I know, I'm a nit-picker). Second, can you show what `tx.executeSql` does? It seems to me that that function should populate `results` with results.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `SELECT` statement might be being called *before* the table has finished being created. Have you tried moving your `SELECT` query to a callback function so that it's called *after* your `CREATE TABLE` SQL has been run. Something like:

```
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table(X, Y, Z UNIQUE)', function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM table', [], function (tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {                 
            console.log(results.rows.item(i).X.text);
            console.log(results.rows.item(i).Y.text);
            console.log(results.rows.item(i).Z.text);                         
        }
    });            
});
```